# "$(...).summernote is not a function" error in Angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, summernote

I am creating a component to use summernote in my angular app but I get "$(...).summernote is not a function" error.
properly after loading the page summernote has not get loaded. but I dont know really what to do to solve this problem.

the code in component:

```
import { Component,OnInit,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {  
constructor( private elementRef:ElementRef){
}
ngOnInit(){
}

 ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log("after view init")

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#summernote').summernote();
  })
 }
}
```

angular.json:

```
    "assets": [
        "src/assets",
        "src/manifest.json",
        "src/icons"
    ],
    "styles": [
        "src/styles.css",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the summernote library *after* the jQuery library:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> "scripts": [
>     "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
>     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
> ]
> ```

### Better

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
]
```

Comment: Looks like this is a "Russian Doll" problem. FIx one problem, lift the doll, and find another problem.

Comment: It is funny, I have spent a lot of time to find a way to get raid of this simple problem but it still exists. 